# Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped) when accessing program arguments

Tags: c

Im currently working on an assignment, and although i'm not done, I've got a basic nested loop that compiles in the unix interface. But when I try running it, I get the Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped) error. Does anyone know whats causing this? Besides the loop, everything else is a template given to us by the professor and I've tried moving the morse array into the main method but I still get the error. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Short description in 2 - 3 sentences.
 *
 * @author     Lastname, Firstname
 * @assignment ICS 212 Assignment XX
 * @date       Today's date
 */

#define SIZE 36

const char *morse[SIZE] = {
    "0 -----",
    "1 .----",
    "2 ..---",
    "3 ...--",
    "4 ....-",
    "5 .....",
    "6 -....",
    "7 --...",
    "8 ---..",
    "9 ----.",
    "a .-",
    "b -...",
    "c -.-.",
    "d -..",
    "e .",
    "f ..-.",
    "g --.",
    "h ....",
    "i ..",
    "j .---",
    "k -.-",
    "l .-..",
    "m --",
    "n -.",
    "o ---",
    "p .--.",
    "q --.-",
    "r .-.",
    "s ...",
    "t -",
    "u ..-",
    "v ...-",
    "w .--",
    "x -..-",
    "y -.--",
    "z --..",
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int i, j;
   // error checking

   // loop through the command line input
   for (i = 0; i <= argc; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
         if ((argv[i+1][j] == morse[i][j]) && ((argv[i+1][j] == '\0') && (morse[i][j] == '\0'))) {
            printf("%c", morse[i][0]);
            break;
         }
         if (argv[i+1][j] != morse[i][j]) {
            break;
         }
         if (argv[i+1][j] == morse[i][j]) {
            continue;
         }
      }
   }
   // convert Morse Code to letter

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i <= argc` and then `argv[i+1]`

Comment: Write an example of how do you run the program and also write the error.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typo. These FAQ "I wrote a i<=n loop and now my program is crashing" array out of bounds questions are very uninteresting and hold no value to future readers.

Answer (score 3):

For the program arguments the rule are:

```
argv[0]        char* to program name (or empty string)
argv[1]        char* to first program argument
argv[2]        char* to second program argument
...
argv[argc-1]   char* to last program argument
argv[argc]     char* equal to NULL
```

So your code shall only look at the range `argv[1]` to `argv[argc-1]`

But here:

```
for (i = 0; i <= argc; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
     if ((argv[i+1][j] ...
               ^^^
               since i can equal argc this is accessing argv[argc+1]
               that is out of bounds.
               Already argv[argc] will cause problems as it is NULL
               and dereferencing a NULL pointer will fail
```

To fix it make sure that you never go further than `argv[argc-1]`

And this

```
for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
```

is rather "dangerous" as 1) the user may give a shorter string and 2) some of the `morse` codes are shorter. Instead you should check `strlen` of both input and `morse` code or break the loop as soon as a `'\0'` is found in one of the strings.

This part

```
     if (argv[i+1][j] == morse[i][j]) {
        continue;
     }
```

is not needed. You are already at the end of the loop so it will `continue` anyway. Just delete the code.

> Besides the loop, everything else is a template given to us by the professor

That's sad because it's a rather bad template. A key-value pair (aka struct) would be much better.

Anyway... your code is not looping the whole `morse` array. You are only trying to compare with a single entry. That's a bug.

To fix it try like:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
     if (strcmp(argv[i], morse[j] + 2) == 0) {
        printf("%c", morse[j][0]);
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: omfg you basically did my homework for me with this one loop. although I needed just to solve this segmentation error, I thank you so much. I didn't know u could +2 on the strcmp function, Jesus

Comment: @Hammahness808 The +2 skips the first two characters in the string compare. But as I wrote: Your professors design is bad - real bad.